# What kinds of changes do ViewChildren and ContentChildren QueryLists listen for?

Tags: angular, reactjs, typescript, angular2-observables, reactivex

Let's say you had the following code:

[image: <code>@ViewChildren('item') items: QueryList<any>;</code>]

And somewhere else the code:

[image: <code>this.items.changes.subscribe(() => {})</code>]

What are the changes that would cause `() => {}` to be called? What about `@ContentChildren()`? I couldn't find any documentation on this.

Additionally, is there a way to get more information about the change that happened? (e.g. the type of change, the element with which the change occurred, etc.)

EDIT: The answer to the "Additionally" portion above can be found in the comments section of the answer that is marked correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both `@ViewChildren` and `@ContentChildren` are used to get a list of Angular components.

So if you have a component `ItemComponent` the binding would be like this.

```
@ViewChildren(ItemComponent) items: QueryList<ItemComponent>;
```

`QueryList` will be a list of objects that are of `ItemComponent` type.

The events in the query list emit when the number of items in the list has changed. Either a component was added or destroyed. This can often often happen when `*ngFor` is used or other template modifiers.

Comment: Can I have template reference variable #test? I don't understand why @ViewChildren('test') example will always yield an empty list.

Comment: @yurzui sorry. You are correct. A string selects a template `#` name and the type will be `ElementRef`. I thought it was for tokens.

Comment: Ah, thank you for your answer. Just one more thing: is there a way to get information about the specific change that occurred?

Comment: @NetherGranite No, the way the logic works inside Angular is to emit a change event every time a template operation changes the DOM structure. I don't even think it bothers to figure out what has changed. Only that it did change. If I needed to track this. I would iterate the items in the query list and tag them with extra data. Any missing that tag would be new items and if the tag is a position then any skips in a number would indicate a deleted item.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia Ah, okay. Thank you!